# How to draw a nice ASCII table in C?

Tags: c, ascii

I want to draw a table like,

```
----------
|   |    |
----------
|   |    |
----------
|   |    |
----------
|   |    |
----------
```

however, it looked messy and ugly :(. Another thing bothered me is the width of each row, since inside each box, contains a number.

```
void draw_table( entry* ptr, int size ) {
    int x = 0;
    for( ; x < size; ++x ) {
        printf( "_____ _____ \n" );
        printf( "| %d | %d | \n", ptr[x].virtual_page, ptr[x].page_frame );
    }
}
```

How could I match the length of the each `"_____"` with the integer (number of digits) inside each box?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the field width format specifier in printf to make all numbers print with a fixed width.  Then you can easily format your table.  For example:

```
printf("|%8d|", 12345);
```

would print:

```
|   12345|
```

See the man page for printf (google "man printf") for all the things you can do.  It can do some pretty powerful formatting.

Answer (score 3):

For each column, you'll need to pre-measure the width of the widest entry in it, then do something like

```
printf("...%.*s...", n, "____________________________");
```

to print `n` underscores. There are other ways but this is the easiest.

Personally I would avoid generating ASCII tables like this and instead generate some higher-level markup like an HTML `<table>` and use existing library code to convert it to plain text, if needed.

Comment: Thank you. This is a simple project, and making the table look nice is optional, so I still prefer a simple way using C.

Comment: By the way, you can use `snprintf(0,0,"%d",n)` to measure the width (in characters) of `n` printed as a decimal number.

Answer (score 2):

BTW, it is nice to draw it with a plus sign also, like this:

```
+-----+-----+
|Head1|...  |
+-----+-----+
|     |     |
|     |     |
```